# TF_NewTensor Segmentation Fault: Possible Bug?

Tags: c++, c, linux, tensorflow, tensorflow-c++

I'm using Tensorflow 2.1 git master branch (commit id:db8a74a737cc735bb2a4800731d21f2de6d04961) and compile it locally. Playing around with the C API to call `TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel` but seems to get segmentation fault. I've managed to drill down the error in the sample code below.

`TF_NewTensor` call is crashing and causing a segmentation fault.

```cpp
int main()
{
    TF_Tensor** InputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*)*1);
    int ndims = 1;
    int64_t* dims = malloc(sizeof(int64_t));
    int ndata = sizeof(int32_t);
    int32_t* data = malloc(sizeof(int32_t));
    dims[0] = 1;
    data[0] = 10;

    // Crash on the next line
    TF_Tensor* int_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_INT32, dims, ndims, data, ndata, NULL, NULL);
    if(int_tensor == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when i move the `TF_Tensor** InputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*)*1);` after the `TF_NewTensor` call, it doesn't crash. Like below:

```cpp
int main()
{

    int ndims = 1;
    int64_t* dims = malloc(sizeof(int64_t));
    int ndata = sizeof(int32_t);
    int32_t* data = malloc(sizeof(int32_t));
    dims[0] = 1;
    data[0] = 10;

    // NO more crash
    TF_Tensor* int_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_INT32, dims, ndims, data, ndata, NULL, NULL);
    if(int_tensor == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK");
    }

    TF_Tensor** InputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*)*1);


    return 0;
}
```

Is it a possible bug or I'm using it wrong? I don't understand how `malloc`q an independent variable could cause a segmentation fault.

can anybody reproduce?

I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008 to compile.

**UPDATE:**

can be further simplified the error as below. This is even without the `InputValues` being allocated.

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tensorflow/c/c_api.h"

int main()
{
    int ndims = 1;
    int ndata = 1;

    int64_t dims[] = { 1 };
    int32_t data[] = { 10 };

    TF_Tensor* int_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_INT32, dims, ndims, data, ndata, NULL, NULL);
    if(int_tensor == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR Tensor");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compile with

`gcc -I<tensorflow_path>/include/ -L<tensorflow_path>/lib test.c -ltensorflow -o test2.out`

**Solution**

As point up by Raz, pass empty `deallocater` instead of NULL, and `ndata` should be size in terms of byte.

```cpp
#include "tensorflow/c/c_api.h"
void NoOpDeallocator(void* data, size_t a, void* b) {}

int main(){
    int ndims = 2;
    int64_t dims[] = {1,1};
    int64_t data[] = {20};
    int ndata = sizeof(int64_t); // This is tricky, it number of bytes not number of element

    TF_Tensor* int_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_INT64, dims, ndims, data, ndata, &NoOpDeallocator, 0);
    if (int_tensor != NULL)\
        printf("TF_NewTensor is OK\n");
    else
        printf("ERROR: Failed TF_NewTensor\n");
}
```

checkout my Github on full code of running/compile TensorFlow's C API [here](https://github.com/AmirulOm/tensorflow_capi_sample)

Comment: I don't see `InputValues` being used anywhere, so how could that be the cause of the crash?

Comment: Did the `malloc` for `InputValues` succeed? I don;t see you check that. If it failed, then in your first code al the other mallocs could fail too.

Comment: Does `ndata` denote the size of `data`? Because you only allocate one int32 to it.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm not using `InputValues` in this example, but in actual code, I use it to call the `SessionRun` API. 

`malloc` does return non-null values,

I did try with `ndata = 1` as Raz Haleva suggested as well. Still same segmentation fault

Comment: @PaulOgilvie see the update code that still producing segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `ndata` to be `sizeof(int32_t)` which is 4.
Your `ndata` is passed as `len` argument to `TF_NewTensor()` which represents the number of elements in `data` (can be seen in [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/c/tf_tensor.h#L77-L80)). Therefore, it should be set to 1 in your example, as you have a single element.

By the way, you can avoid using `malloc()` here (as you don't check for return values, and this may be error-pront and less elegant in general) and just use local variables instead.

**UPDATE**

In addition, you pass `NULL` both for `deallocator` and `deallocator_arg`. I'm pretty sure this is the issue as the comment states *"Clients must provide a custom deallocator function..."* (can be seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/c/tf_tensor.h#L71)). The `deallocator` is called by the `TF_NewTensor()` (can be seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/c/tf_tensor.cc#L134)) and this may be the cause for the segmentation fault.

So, summing it all up, try the next code:

```
void my_deallocator(void * data, size_t len, void * arg)
{
    printf("Deallocator called with data %p\n", data);
}

void main()
{
    int64_t dims[] = { 1 };
    int32_t data[] = { 10 };

    ... = TF_NewTensor(TF_INT32, dims, /*num_dims=*/ 1, data, /*len=*/ 1, my_deallocator, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I tried to set `ndata` to 1, but yet the same segmentation fault. Also, I change `dims` and `data` as you mentioned. I wonder somebody else could reproduce it or is it just in my environment.

Comment: Funny thing, if I set my `data`,`dims` and `ndata` as you mention, I get segmentation fault EVEN without allocating `InputValues`

Comment: Please refer to the new code update that are still crashing.

Comment: @AmirulOm please refer to the update section and do not pass `NULL` both for `deallocator` and `deallocator_arg`. Let me know if it helped!

Comment: Thanks, I figure it by run debugging it through GDB. There is two error. 1) passing NULL to `deallocater`, should have pass empty `deallocater`. 2) `len` is actually size in terms of byte, note length.